# How can i establish federated communication between two separate Hyperledger fabric System

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am new to blockchain Development. Right now i am thinking about creating a interblockchain Communication way ,
where to users from two seperate System can access into Cross Ledger system.User from system-1 can access data from  system-2 by getting authorized by the system.
Please give me some resources on this , how should i start my approach? if a system like this already exists, information would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the data isolation between both systems, and if you do not mind them sharing the same network topology, then try channels.

But if you want to keep the systems seperate and want to establish two different networks, take a look at [Hyperledger Cactus](https://www.hyperledger.org/use/cactus). It does way more than you want.